# Numeronyms or N8s?

Tags: code-golf, string

A [numeronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym) (also known as a "numerical contraction") is when a word is shortened using numbers. A common contraction method is to use the length of the replaced substring to replace all but the first and last characters. For example, use [`i18n` instead of `internationalization`, or `L10n` instead of `localization`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization). (The `L` is capitalized since a lowercase one looks too similar to the `1`.)

Of course, several words in the same phrase may have the same abbreviated form, so your job is to convert a group of words to their numeronyms, or in the event that there exists some *different* words with the same numeronym, your program should give a result of `A7s R4t`, short for `Ambiguous Result` (yes, I know that this result is itself an ambiguous result.)

### Rules:

- Use a program or function, and print or return the result.
- Input is taken as a single string.
- The output is a single string of space-delimited words.
- Your program need not convert words with length 3, and should not convert shorter words.
- If an `l` (lowercase ell) would occur before a `1` (one), it should be made uppercase.
- If an `I` (uppercase eye) would occur before a `1` (one), it should be made lowercase.
- Input will be printable ASCII and spaces. Words are separated by spaces.
- Shortest code wins.

### Examples:

```
A7s R4t -> A7s R4t (OR: A1s R1t, etc)
Ambiguous Result -> A7s R4t
Billy goats gruff -> B3y g3s g3f
Thanks for the Memories -> T4s f1r the M6s (one possible answer, NOT: Thnks fr th Mmrs)
Programming Puzzles & Code Golf -> P9g P5s & C2e G2f
globalization -> g11n
localizability -> L12y
Internationalization or antidisestablishmentarianism -> i18n or a26m
Internationalization or InternXXXXXalization -> A7s R4t
what is this fiddle and faddle -> A7s R4t
A be see -> A be s1e (OR: A be see)
see sea -> s1e s1a (OR: see sea)
2B or not 2B -> 2B or not 2B (OR: 2B or n1t 2B. 2 letters, don't change, don't count as ambiguous)
this example is this example -> t2s e5e is t2s e5e (same words aren't ambiguous)
l1 -> l1 (2 letters, don't change.)
I1 -> I1 (2 letters, don't change.)
```

Edit: If anyone didn't get the reference: [Thnks fr th Mmrs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thnks_fr_th_Mmrs)

Comment: Can the input contain numbers as well? If so, does an input of `l1` become `L1` or stay as `l1`?

Comment: I presume from the emphasis on *different* that `example example` would be `e5e e5e`, but it would be good to include a test case which covers this.

Comment: Added test cases for both of your questions (`2B or not 2B` and after.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## J, 92 bytes

```
(' 'joinstring(<&(]`(rplc&('I1';'i1')&(rplc&('l1';'L1'))&({.,([:":#-2:),{:))@.(#>3:))&>&;:))
```

A looong chain of composed calls.
The first part is just a fork: a literal, `joinstring`, and a function (in J, `1 (10 + +) 2` is `(10 + (1 + 2))`).
The second part is the function. The two `rplc` calls are to replace the I/l when they could be confused.
`&` is composition, and composing an operator with a value curries. (so `3&+` gives a function that expects the 2nd argument to be added).
Finally, the last part is the function that takes the first, the length-2 (composed with stringification), and the last.
the `&>&;:` bit at the end composes this function (which should be applied to every argument) to `>` (unboxing), because `;:` (split words) returns a boxed list (so that every element can have different length).

example:

```
     (' 'joinstring(<&(]`(rplc&('I1';'i1')&(rplc&('l1';'L1'))&({.,([:":#-2:),{:))@.(#>3:))&>&;:)) 'hey you baby Iooooooooneey I1'
hey you b2y i11y I1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Caché ObjectScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cach%C3%A9_ObjectScript), 231 bytes

```
r(a,b) s o=$REPLACE(o,a,b) q
z(s) f i=1:1:$L(s," ") s u=$P(s," ",i),l=$L(u),o=$S(l<4:u,1:$E(u)_(l-2)_$E(u,l)) d:l>3 r("I1","i1"),r("l1","L1") d  g:r z+4
    . i '(l<4!(v(o)=u!'$D(v(o)))) s r=1 q
    . s v(o)=u,t=t_o_" "
    q t
    q "A7s R4t"
```

This would be good-ol' standards-compliant MUMPS if it weren't for that pesky `$REPLACE` call, which isn't part of the standard. Reimplementing it in pure M takes a good 80ish bytes, so I didn't go down that route.

The entry point is `$$z("your string here")`, which returns `"y2r s4g h2e"`, and so forth.

Comment: Could you perhaps link to the language? I haven't heard of it.

Comment: I mean, it's the thing that comes up when you google for it (http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=TCOS) - a proprietary flavor of MUMPS.

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <s>280</s> 274 bytes

First time golfer here! Been enjoying reading these lately and so I thought I might try out some myself! Probably not the best solution, but oh well!

```
class B{static void Main(string[] a){string[] n=Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');string o="";int j,i=j=0;for(;j<n.Length;j++){int s=n[j].Length;n[j]=((s<4)?n[j]:""+n[j][0]+(s-2)+n[j][s-1])+" ";o+=n[j];for(;i<j;i++)if(n[j]==n[i]){o="A7s R4t";j=n.Length;}}Console.WriteLine(o);}}
```

Same thing ungolfed:

```
class B
{
    static void Main(string[] a)
    {            
        string[] n = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        string o = "";
        int j, i = j = 0;
        for(; j < n.Length;j++)
        {
            int s = n[j].Length;

            n[j] = ((s<4) ? n[j] : "" + n[j][0] + (s - 2) + n[j][s - 1]) + " ";
            o += n[j];
            for (; i < j; i++)
            {
                if (n[j] == n[i]) { o = "A7s R4t"; j=n.Length;}
            }                              
        }
        Console.WriteLine(o);
    }
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! c:

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <strike>131</strike> 120 bytes

I've added a byte for using the `-p` switch:

```perl
s/\B(\w+)(\w)/length($1)."$2_$1"/ge;$_="A7s R4t\n"if/(\w\d+\w)(\w+)\b.*\1(?!\2)/;s/_\w+//g;s/I1\w/\l$&/g;s/l1\w/\u$&/g;
```

#### Explanation

```perl
# Replace internal letters with count, but keep them around for the next test.
s/\B(\w+)(\w)/length($1)."$2_$1"/ge;
# Detect ambiguous result
$_ = "A7s R4t\n" if
    # Use negative look-ahead assertion to find conflicts
    /(\w\d+\w)(\w+)\b.*\1(?!\2)/;
# We're done with the internal letters now
s/_\w+//g;
# Transform case of initial 'I' and 'l', but only before '1'
s/I1\w/\l$&/g;
s/l1\w/\u$&/g;
```

Comment: Not sure whether is correct but I expected the “l” in “like” to not get capitalized when transformed into “l2e”, as is not followed by “1”.

Comment: Tested just a couple of cases, but seem to work: `s/(\w)(\w+)(\w)/$1.length($2)."$3_$2"/ge` → `s/\B(\w+)(\w)/length($1)."$2_$1"/ge`.

Comment: Thanks, @manatwork.  I overlooked the requirement to caseswap `[Il]` only before `1` - saved a couple of bytes, too!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 165 bytes

```js
s=>(r=s.replace(/\S+/g,w=>(m=w.length-2)<2?w:(i=d.indexOf(n=((m+s)[0]<2&&{I:"i",l:"L"}[w[0]]||w[0])+m+w[m+1]))>=0&d[i+1]!=w?v=0:d.push(n,w)&&n,v=d=[]),v?r:"A7s R4t")
```

### Explanation

```js
s=>(                         // s = input string
  r=s.replace(               // r = result of s with words replaced by numeronyms
    /\S+/g,                  // match each word
    w=>                      // w = matched word
      (m=w.length-2)         // m = number of characters in the middle of the word
        <2?w:                // if the word length is less than 4 leave it as it is
      (i=d.indexOf(          // check if this numeronym has been used before
        n=                   // n = numeronymified word
          ((m+s)[0]<2&&      // if the number starts with 1 we may need to replace
            {I:"i",l:"L"}    //     the first character with one of these
              [w[0]]||w[0])+ // return the replaced or original character
          m+w[m+1]
      ))>=0&d[i+1]!=w?       // set result as invalid if the same numeronym has been
        v=0:                 //     used before with a different word
      d.push(n,w)&&n,        // if everything is fine return n and add it to the list
    v=                       // v = true if result is valid
      d=[]                   // d = array of numeronyms used followed by their original word
  ),
  v?r:"A7s R4t"              // return the result
)
```

### Test

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="lnternationalization or antidisestablishmentarianism" />
<button onclick='result.textContent=(

s=>(r=s.replace(/\S+/g,w=>(m=w.length-2)<2?w:(i=d.indexOf(n=((m+s)[0]<2&&{I:"i",l:"L"}[w[0]]||w[0])+m+w[m+1]))>=0&d[i+1]!=w?v=0:d.push(n,w)&&n,v=d=[]),v?r:"A7s R4t")

)(input.value)'>Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 162

```js
w=>(v=(w=w.split` `).map(x=>(l=x.length-2+'')>1?((l[0]>1||{I:'i',l:'L'})[x[0]]||x[0])+l+x[-~l]:x)).some((a,i)=>v.some((b,j)=>a==b&w[i]!=w[j]))?'A7s R4t':v.join` `
```

**Less golfed**

```js
// Less golfed
f=w=>{
  w = w.split` ` // original text splitted in words
  v = w.map(x=> { // build modified words in array v

    l = x.length - 2 // word length - 2
    if (l > 1) // if word length is 4 or more
    {
      a = x[0] // get first char of word
      l = l+'' // convert to string to get the first digit
      m = l[0] > 1 || {I:'i', l:'L'} // only if first digit is 1, prepare to remap I to i and l to L
      a = m[a] || a // remap
      return a + l + x[-~l] // note: -~ convert back to number and add 1
    }
    else
      return x // word unchanged
  })
  return v.some((a,i)=>v.some((b,j)=>a==b&w[i]!=w[j])) // look for equals Numeronyms on different words
  ? 'A7s R4t' 
  : v.join` `
}
```

**Test**

```js
F=w=>(v=(w=w.split` `).map(x=>(l=x.length-2+'')>1?((l[0]>1||{I:'i',l:'L'})[x[0]]||x[0])+l+x[-~l]:x)).some((a,i)=>v.some((b,j)=>a==b&w[i]!=w[j]))?'A7s R4t':v.join` `

console.log=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n'

;['A7s R4t','Ambiguous Result','Billy goats gruff','Thanks for the Memories',
'Programming Puzzles & Code Golf','globalization','localizability',
'Internationalization or antidisestablishmentarianism',  
'Internationalization or InternXXXXXalization','what is this fiddle and faddle',
'A be see','see sea','2B or not 2B','this example is this example','l1','I1']
.forEach(t=>console.log(t+' -> '+F(t)))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 185 bytes

```python
d={}
r=''
for w in input().split():
 l=len(w);x=(w[0]+`l-2`+w[-1]).replace('l1','L1').replace('I1','i1')
 if l<4:x=w
 if d.get(x,w)!=w:r='A7s R4t';break
 d[x]=w;r+=x+' '
print r.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Factor, <s>48</s> 35 bytes, noncompeting

It's a lambda that goes on the stack, that doesn't technically meet the *really annoyingly hard* requirements that I originally managed to overlook.

```
[ " " split [ a10n ] map " " join ]
```

Uses the `english` vocabulary.

Or, if we inline the `a10n` library word, then 131 bytes (with auto-imports):

```
: a ( b -- c ) " " split [ dup length 3 > [ [ 1 head ] [ length 2 - number>string ] [ 1 tail* ] tri 3append ] when ] map " " join ;
```

Comment: Does this handle the i/L stuff and A7s R4t?

Comment: @RobertFraser I'm certain it does, though I'm not at a Factor compiler this minute; I'll add passing unit tests when I am. :D

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the requirements. A week after I finished the question, I was like "oh no, what have I done," but it was too late. I might make a simpler version as a separate challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 160

I'd love to find a good way to replace those replace calls.

```
def f(a):y=[(x,(x[0]+str(len(x)-2)+x[-1]).replace('l1','L1').replace('I1','i1'))[len(x)>3]for x in a.split()];return('A7s R4t',' '.join(y))[len(set(y))==len(y)]
```

With some test cases:

```
assert f('Billy goats gruff') == 'B3y g3s g3f'
assert f('Programming Puzzles & Code Golf') == 'P9g P5s & C2e G2f'
assert f('Internationalization or InternXXXXXalization') == 'A7s R4t'
```